# opencart seo tweak

Tags: php, url, seo, opencart

Can anyone help me tweak my opencart seo_url file so that my blog entries have the seo keyword picked up from the url_alias table and displayed as mypage.co.uk/blog/post1 instead of what it is doing now which is mypage.co.uk/blog?news_id=9

If i remove the line `'information/news'      => 'blog',` then it picks the seo keyword assigned to the blog post correctly from the table but the url displays as mypage.co.uk/post1

The following code may help anyone that is looking to have a more complete set of seo optimised urls beyond what opencart offers.

```
    <?php
class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
        /* SEO Custom URL */
        private $url_list = array (
            'common/home'       => '',
            'checkout/cart'     => 'basket',
            'account/register'  => 'register',
                        'account/wishlist'  => 'wishlist',
                        'checkout/checkout' => 'checkout',
                        'account/login'     => 'login',
                        'product/special'   => 'special',
                        'affiliate/account' => 'affiliate',
                        'checkout/voucher'  => 'voucher',
                        'product/manufacturer' => 'brand',
                        'account/newsletter'   => 'newsletter',
                        'account/order'        => 'order',
                        'account/account'      => 'account',
                        'information/contact'  => 'contact',
                        'account/return/insert' => 'return/insert',
                        'information/sitemap'   => 'sitemap',
            'information/news'      => 'blog',
            );
        /* SEO Custom URL */

    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }   

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
                }
            }
                         /* SEO Custom URL */
                         if ( $_s = $this->setURL($this->request->get['_route_']) ) {
                                 $this->request->get['route'] = $_s;
                         }/* SEO Custom URL */

            if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $url_data = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

            $url = ''; 

            $data = array();

            parse_str($url_data['query'], $data);

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($data['route'])) {
                    if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                            unset($data[$key]);
                        }                   
                    } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                        $categories = explode('_', $value);

                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                            if ($query->num_rows) {
                                $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                            }                           
                        }

                        unset($data[$key]);
                     }// 
                                        /* SEO Custom URL */
                                        if( $_u = $this->getURL($data['route']) ){
                                            $url .= $_u;
                                            unset($data[$key]);
                                        }/* SEO Custom URL */        


                                }
                        }

            if ($url) {
                unset($data['route']);

                $query = '';

                if ($data) {
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
                    }

                    if ($query) {
                        $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');
                    }
                }

                return $url_data['scheme'] . '://' . $url_data['host'] . (isset($url_data['port']) ? ':' . $url_data['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_data['path']) . $url . $query;
            } else {
                return $link;
            }
        } else {
            return $link;
        }       
    }
        /* SEO Custom URL */
        public function getURL($route) {
                if( count($this->url_list) > 0) {
                     foreach ($this->url_list as $key => $value) {
                        if($route == $key) {
                            return '/'.$value;
                        }
                     }
                }
                return false;
        }
        public function setURL($_route) {
                if( count($this->url_list) > 0 ){
                     foreach ($this->url_list as $key => $value) {
                        if($_route == $value) {
                            return $key;
                        }
                     }
                }
                return false;
        }/* SEO Custom URL */   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only an advice how to move on:

In Your `rewrite` method there is the part `if ($url) { ... }` where the `?news_id=1` or `&news_id=1` is added to the end of URL.

I would do a testing here similar to what is being tested in the `index` method - to find out whether it is a product, manufacturer, information, category, news, etc and replace that with its SEO keyword - whether from `url_alias` table or from the corresponding table...

Then instead of adding `?news_id=1` or `&news_id=1` You would just add `/<SEO_KEYWORD>`...

Comment: do you know what code i need to change. sorry im new to this. i understand the logic youre implying. just not sure how to implement